# Firefox, websockets and odd behaviours

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, websocket, playframework-2.0

**Background:**

- Using WebSockets with JavaScript + Play! framework (2.2).
- Can send and receive data fine in Chrome.
- Can only receive data (**from server**) in Firefox as send() doesn't trigger any callbacks.

In addition to the **send** issue, and in Firefox **only** again, the tab for the page is always stuck on "connecting" while the spinner keeps spinning (see figure 1).

**Misbehaving Browser:**
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0)(*Firefox 24.0*)

[image: Spinning Snapshot]

> (**Figure 1**. Firefox tab after page has loaded and data is shown)

Any time I refresh the web page, I receive the error below, attributed to the constant page loading behaviour I'm sure.

```
The connection to ws://localhost:9000/ was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

#### The entire JavaScript code:

---

```
$(function() {
    var chatSocket = new WebSocket("@routes.Application.getMetaData().webSocketURL(request)");

    var sendMessage = function() {
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            id: "unique",
            name: "a name",
            age: 22
        }));
    }

    var receiveEvent = function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data)
        document.write(data.age);
        document.write(data.name);
        document.write(data.message);
        document.write("\n");
        sendMessage();
        chatSocket.close();
    }
    chatSocket.onmessage = receiveEvent
})
```

Now In the past, I've been trying with `MozWebSocket` instead of the standard `WebSocket`, but I get nothing rendered on screen using that module therefore unless there is an angle I've missed, `WebSocket` is the better one to use.

#### The relevant Play! block:

---

```
public static WebSocket<JsonNode> getMetaData() {
    return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {

        // Called when the Websocket Handshake is done.
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out) {

            // For each event received on the socket,
            in.onMessage(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
                @Override
                public void invoke(JsonNode jsonNode) {
                    System.out.println("Message Incoming!");
                    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("id"));
                    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("name"));
                    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("age"));
                }
            });


            // When the socket is closed.
            in.onClose(new Callback0() {
                public void invoke() {
                    System.out.println("Disconnected");

                }
            });

            ObjectNode node = Json.newObject();
            node.put("message", "hello");
            node.put("name", "client");
            node.put("age", 1);

            out.write(node);

            //same result commented/uncommented
            out.close();
        }
    };
}
```

So in **Chrome**, the flow would be:

1. document.write(...)
2. "Message Incoming!"
3. ... JSON attributes
4. "Disconnected"

But in **Firefox**, the flow is:

1. document.write(...)
2. "Disconnected"

Any help in diagnosing these problems would be greatly appreciated. I have no intention of supporting IE, but having both Mozilla and Chrome working would be great.

#### Other JavaScript Warnings:

Below is a warning I occasionally get in Firefox's console while pointing at the "ws" protocol as the culprit. What its relevance is to my problem, I do not know.

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `document.write()` after the document is loaded, which then [implies `document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes) which in turn replaces the document and by that unloads the old one and aborts stuff like timeouts or websockets.

Use something other than `document.write()` and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh how I hate you! I didn't want this solution to work, but it totally does. I only considered using document.write() to see if the sockets worked in the first place. Thank you so much though.